# How to open a file using Visual Studio debugger commands

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

Is it possible to open a file using debugger commands options of Visual Studio?
For example I want to run my program (with some command arguments) and then open a file.
The cmd equivalent would be:

```
app.exe args & file.png
```

Can I do the same thing in visual studio using projects settings or any other way?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use dev command prompt inside Visual Studio to achieve the same result
You can open Developer Command Prompt from Tools > Command Line menu

[image]

Then just type in whatever command you use in cmd